# Weird behavior using std::make_exception_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I am wondering why `std::current_exception()` works differently in this situation:

```
std::exception_ptr e, e2;
try {
    std::string("abcd").substr(42);
} catch(std::exception &ex) {
    std::cerr << "(1) Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    e = std::current_exception();
    e2 = std::make_exception_ptr(ex);
}
handle_exception(e);
handle_exception(e2);
```

Whereas handle_exception prints the exception:

```
void handle_exception(std::exception_ptr e)
{
    try {
        if (e)
            std::rethrow_exception(e);
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
(1) Exception: basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 42) > this->size() (which is 4)
(2) Exception: basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 42) > this->size() (which is 4)
(3) Exception: std::exception
```

However I would expect the following output:

```
(1) Exception: basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 42) > this->size() (which is 4)
(2) Exception: basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 42) > this->size() (which is 4)
(3) Exception: basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 42) > this->size() (which is 4)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::make_exception_ptr()` takes its argument by value. This means either a copy or in-place construction.

You're making a copy of the std::exception (i.e. slicing)

Comment: I understand it is a copy as described in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/make_exception_ptr. But why would that matter?

Comment: @ypnos because `std::exception` was designed using object oriented inheritance based polymorphism, not type erasure based polymorphism?

Comment: In the website I linked it says: "This is done as if executing the following code: …" basically doing the same thing as I am doing. And what would be the purpose of std::make_exception_ptr() if it always creates a meaningless copy of the exception?

Comment: @ypnos std::exception is a base class. You would never write `auto x = std::make_exception_ptr(std::exception(...));`

Comment: @ypnos you can create an exception pointer from the actual type you want to throw, instead of from the base type?  Your code uses `std::exception &` and `std::exception_ptr`, neither of which copy or slice.  `make_exception_ptr` lets you create an exception in one context, and throw it in another (say create it in one thread, and throw it in another).  It is not intended to capture the current exception, that is what `current_exception` is for...

Answer (score 6):

#### About C++ `throw`

It's important to note that C++ `throw` (I will only talk about its usage with operand, like `throw someExpression;`) **is sensitive to type** of passed operand. It copies its operand (copy-initializes an auxiliary object from it). And copying is done according to (lexical) type of the operand (not by getting class dynamically).

E.g.:

```cpp
try {
    std::runtime_error myException("Some test message");
    std::exception &upcastedMyException = myException;
    throw upcastedMyException; //std::exception is thrown
} catch(const std::exception &caught) {
    std::cout << caught.what() << std::endl; //will output "std::exception"
}
```

It differs from other languages, e.g. Java:

```java
try {
    RuntimeException myException = new RuntimeException();
    Exception upcastedMyException = myException;
    throw upcastedMyException; //RuntimeException is thrown
} catch(Exception caught) {
    System.out.println(caught.getClass()); //will output "java.lang.RuntimeException"
}
```

Therefore it's very important that expression passed to C++ `throw` has correct type. In my first example, replacing `throw upcastedMyException` with (for example) `throw static_cast<const std::runtime_error &>(upcastedMyException)` would change the output.

#### About `std::make_exception_ptr`

`std::make_exception_ptr`, on its hand, is implemented in quite simple way through `throw`:

```cpp
template<class E> std::exception_ptr make_exception_ptr(E e) noexcept {
    try {
        throw e; //note this line
    } catch(...) {
        return std::current_exception();
    }
}
```

This means that `std::make_exception_ptr` is sensitive to passed template argument; if template argument isn't passed explicitly, then `std::make_exception_ptr` is sensitive to (lexical) type of passed function argument (which influences deduction of template argument):

- If you do `std::make_exception_ptr(ex)` in your code (where `ex` is declared as `const std::exception &`), then `std::exception` would be thrown within `std::make_exception_ptr` and `std::make_exception_ptr` would return `std::exception_ptr` related to `std::exception`.
- If you do `std::make_exception_ptr(static_cast<const std::logic_error &>(ex))` in your code, then `std::logic_error` would be thrown within `std::make_exception_ptr` and `std::make_exception_ptr` would return `std::exception_ptr` related to `std::logic_error`.
- If you do `std::make_exception_ptr(static_cast<const std::out_of_range &>(ex))` in your code, then `std::out_of_range` would be thrown within `std::make_exception_ptr` and `std::make_exception_ptr` would return `std::exception_ptr` related to `std::out_of_range`.